# What is the number in the "Low Answer Score" in the review section?

Tags: support, flagging

Looking at the current flags on an answer, I see the following line:

> Low answer quality score [66], /questions/how-to-answer shown and skipped

I have seen other numbers in the otherwise same text on other answers. What is the significance of the number in brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a rough measure of the probable quality of a post. Every post starts at a score of 100, and there are various metrics applied to the post that can reduce the score. A post hits the queue and gets an auto-flag if it scores below 80.

More [on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72523/172958).

Comment: Thanks, that was very informative.